# Dagger 2 - How to have an Activity as Subcomponent of another Activity

Tags: android, dagger-2

The Parent Activity has some state information (in its presenter) that the Child Activity should have access to.

**AppComponent:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {MainActivityModule.class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance Builder application(App application);
        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

**MainActivityModule:**

```
@Module
public abstract class MainActivityModule {
    @MainActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = SubActivityModule.class) // <- not working!?
    abstract MainActivity mainActivity();
}
```

**SubActivityModule:**

```
@Module
public abstract class SubActivityModule {
    @SubActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract SubActivity subActivity();
}
```

Both activities are inherited from `DaggerAppCompatActivity`. In the MainActivity I try to open the SubActivity like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

So the application compiles fine and starts up. MainActivity is launched. As soon as I try to launch the SubActivity I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class`<ditest.SubActivity>`

Why is this not working? Can such a relationship not be achieved with Dagger 2? Can I do it differently somehow?